# How to safely add new key-value pair into go native map

Tags: multithreading, dictionary, go, thread-safety, mutex

I want to add a new key-value pair into Golang map from concurrent threads. Problem is that if there is a key present in the map we don't create new pair. From multithreaded perspective how to check the current condition and if key isn't present insert the key - value.

Is there any way to organize code to add key safely when first encountered?

The main problem is safely initializing mutex

Comment: `sync.Map` would not be well-suited for this scenario anyway, as there is no "StoreIfMissing" operation. The most obvious solution is to have a `map` that is guarded by a `sync.RWMutex`. When trying to write a value, lock the mutex, then only write the value if the key is not in the map.

Comment: You cannot write any values in go concurrently without synchronization, and tagging this with `mutex` implies you know you need a mutex, so what is the question exactly if you have a lock around the map already?

Comment: In that case I need to stop all other reads too from accessing the value. also locking global mutex on every write operation is really time consuming. I just want to guard writing when its initializing value (not modifying already existing key - value)

Comment: @shotasilagadze: You've benchmarked this in your application? Are you sure it's not performant enough for your scenario?

Comment: I just want to know the solution for this kind of scenario not for a particular case. @TimCooper

Comment: "I just want to guard writing when its initializing value (not modifying already existing key - value)" So you intend to have a race condition on modifying existing values?

Comment: The solution for this "this kind of scenario" is almost always a mutex and map, until you have benchmarks proving otherwise. From the sync documentation: `The Map type is specialized. Most code should use a plain Go map instead, with separate locking or coordination, for better type safety and to make it easier to maintain other invariants along with the map content`

Comment: @TimCooper I just don't change anything after inserting value. I just save something for further retrieval. that's it. I just want the insertion to be thread safe. what's so confusing here

Comment: You can't have thread-safe insertions without also making all reads thread-safe. If the use is mostly-read, then use a RWMutex to allow multiple readers, but if there are going to be _any_ writes you can't get around synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to organize code to add key safely when first encountered?

No. You *need* proper synchronisation.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the combination of [`sync.Map`](https://godoc.org/sync#Map) to store the key-values and [`sync.Once`](https://godoc.org/sync#Once) inside of the value to perform the one-time initialization.

Here is an example:

```golang
type Value struct {
    init       sync.Once
    someValue  string
}

func (v *Value) Init() {
    v.init.Do(func() {
        // This function will only be executed one time
        v.someValue = "initialized"
    })
}

func main() {
    var m sync.Map

    v1, _ := m.LoadOrStore("key", &Value{})
    v1.(*Value).Init() // init function is called

    v2, _ := m.LoadOrStore("key", &Value{})
    v2.(*Value).Init() // init function is not called
}
```